# Как проверить пароль на соответствие правилам

Tags: python, алгоритм

Привет!Вот такая задача с сервиса:
Стефан и София забывают о безопасности и используют простые пароли для всего.
Помогите Николе разработать модуль для проверки паролей на безопасность.
Пароль считается достаточно стойким, если его длина больше или равна 10 символам, 
он содержит, как минимум одну цифру, одну букву в верхнем и одну в нижнем регистре.
Пароль может содержать только латинские буквы и/или цифры.

Вх. данные: Пароль как строка.

Вых. данные: Безопасность пароля в виде булевого значения (bool) или любого типа данных,
который может быть сконвертирован и представлен как булево значение (True или False)

```
checkio('A1213pokl') == False
checkio('bAse730onE') == True
checkio('asasasasasasasaas') == False
checkio('QWERTYqwerty') == False
checkio('123456123456') == False
checkio('QwErTy911poqqqq') == True
```

Предусловия:
re.match("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", password)
0 < len(password) ≤ 64

Решаю так:

```
import re
def checkio(data):
        if len(data)<10:
            return False
        patern_nijn=re.compile('[a-z]') 
        patern_verhn=re.compile('[A-Z]') 
        countBukvVVerhnRegistre=0
        countBukvVNijnemRegistre=0
        for chunk_let in data:
            if  patern_nijn.match(chunk_let):
                countBukvVNijnemRegistre+=1
            elif  patern_verhn.match(chunk_let):
                countBukvVVerhnRegistre+=1 
        if countBukvVNijnemRegistre!=1 :
            return False
        if countBukvVVerhnRegistre!=1 :
            return False

        #replace this for solution
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
        #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
        assert checkio('A1213pokl') == False,checkio('A1213pokl') 
        assert checkio('bAse730onE4') == True, "2nd example"
        assert checkio('asasasasasasasaas') == False, "3rd example"
        assert checkio('QWERTYqwerty') == False, "4th example"
        assert checkio('123456123456') == False, "5th example"
        assert checkio('QwErTy911poqqqq') == True, "6th example"
        print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to review your tests and earn cool rewards!")
```

Не проходит assert:

```
assert checkio('bAse730onE4') == True, "2nd example"
```

Не могу 'скомпоновать' алгоритм чтобы учитывал заданные условия.

Comment: У вас `+=1` даёт больше, чем 1 на выходе. Попробуйте заменить проверку на `<1` или `!=0`

Comment: это не влияет на результат в вашем коде, но в `''.isalpha` и `''.isalpha()` это разные вещи в Питоне

Comment: Исправил так:`if countBukvVNijnemRegistre>0 and countBukvVVerhnRegistre>0:
  return True
 else:
  return False`.Теперь на assert assert checkio('QWERTYqwerty') == False, "4th example"
AssertionError: 4th example

Comment: @jfs я убрал код `''.isalpha()` ,оставил только регексы т.к. думаю она на код не влияет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пароль считается достаточно стойким, если его длина больше или равна 10 символам, он содержит, как минимум одну цифру, одну букву в верхнем и одну в нижнем регистре. Пароль может содержать только латинские буквы и/или цифры.

```
import string

def isvalid(password):
    has_no = set(password).isdisjoint
    return not (len(password) < 10
                or has_no(string.digits)
                or has_no(string.ascii_lowercase)
                or has_no(string.ascii_uppercase))
```

Пример:

```
>>> isvalid('bAse730onE4')
True
```

Помимо необходимости замены `!= 1` на `< 1`, код в вопросе ещё не проверяет наличие цифр.

Comment: обьясните пожалуйста метод set в коде,к какому обьекту класса он принадлежит?

Comment: @Константин [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#set) это класс. Если не ясно что [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) делает,  то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, специально об этом (это может быть полезно в более общем контексте и для других людей).

Comment: Ага понятно)Все понял)