# Хотя бы один символ верхнего и нижнего регистра, и цифра

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть случайная строка. Если в ней нет хотя бы одного символа верхнего или нижнего регистра или цифры, то исправить ей таким образом, чтобы после исправления был хотя бы один символ верхнего, хотя бы один символ нижнего регистра и любая цифра. Как можно сделать такое без большого количества if'ов, но не меняя длину строки?

Comment: `любая_строка + 'aA0'` гарантирует что результат всегда содержит желаемые категории.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как проверить пароль на соответствие правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796439/23044)

Comment: @jfs Нужно, чтобы размер остался тот же. Сейчас уточню заданный вопрос

Comment: `любая_строка[:-3] + 'aA0'` сохраняет длину строки.

Comment: @jfs, только если длина исходной не меньше)

Comment: @vp_arth строка обязана содержать как минимум 3 символа

Answer (score -1):

Ну у меня получилось в четыре `if-а` (а вообще я мог все слить в одно громадное, но это как-то слишком). Да, этот вариант довольно длинный, но все же уместен. И вот почему:цифры и буквы верхнего и нижнего регистра добавляются при *необходимости*, а не всегда (то есть: если нет цифры, то она добавляется). Если это нужно для паролей, то такой вариант сойдет. Только вот в`elsе-ы` нужно доработать добавив рандом. Ну это уже не так сложно.

Основные моменты кода:

> 1.Добавление строки  `string`
>   2.Проверка на её длинну
>   3.Проверка на содержание цифр
>   4.Проверка на содержание малых и заглавных букв (у малых букв есть небольшое отличие в проверке: т.к. цифры тоже малые символы, то идет сравнение с длинной списка чисел, содержащихся в строке)
>   5.Корриктеровка строки в соответствии с вышеперечисленными
>   проверками.

```
string = input('')
    if len(string) > 2:
       if len([s for s in string if s in list('1234567890')]) > 0:
           if len([s for s in string if s.islower()]) > len([s for s in string if s in list('1234567890')]:
              if len([s for s in string if s.isupper()]) > 0:
                  pass
              else:
                  string = list(string)
                  string[0] = 'I'
                  string = ''.join(string)
           else:
                  string = list(string)
                  string[1] = 'z'
                  string = ''.join(string)
       else:  
                  string = list(string)
                  string[2] = '8'
                  string = ''.join(string)
```

Comment: "Если это нужно для паролей, то такой вариант сойдёт" - Правда? Каким образом? Ну и: в пароль без цифр и капса, ваш алгоритм не добавит капс..

Comment: @vp-arth Хорошо, исправлю